# How to turn characters into numbers from a column in a dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe, character, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe in the following form:

```
 Date     equity company  press Categorization  Year Month Event greenwashing
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>          <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>       
1 07/30/21   153. JPMorgan NA    NA                NA NA       NA 0           
2 07/29/21   153  JPMorgan NA    NA                NA NA       NA 0           
3 07/28/21   152. JPMorgan NA    NA                NA NA       NA 0           
4 07/27/21   151. JPMorgan NA    NA                NA NA       NA 0           
5 07/26/21   152. JPMorgan NA    NA                NA NA       NA 0           
6 07/23/21   151. JPMorgan NA    NA                NA NA       NA 0
```

In the column 'greenwashing' there are some variables that are in the format character such as: The Guardian, Financial Times, among others. I need to turn these characters into 1.

I already tried to name a word list and use the if else code:

```
word.list = c("Financial Times",
              "The Guardian", 
              "Mena Report",
              "States News Service",
              "US Newshire",
              "DeSmogBlog",
              "PR Newshire",
              "The New York Times")
if(word.list){
  print("1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tidyverse:
Let's say your data frame is `df`, working off your attempt

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- mutate(df, greenwashing = ifelse(greenwashing %in% word.list, 1, greenwashing)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this easily by converting the logical to integer with `+`

```
df$greenwashing <- +(df$greenwashing %in% word.list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try -

```
df$greenwashing <- as.integer(df$greenwashing %in% word.list)
```

This will change all the `word.list` values to 1 and rest to 0